# Calculating infinite sums arithmetically

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm having a hard time understanding where I've gone wrong in calculating the result for the infinite series shown below. Based on Mr. Woo's [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P913qwtXihk), I've gotten the wrong result, but I don't see anything wrong that I've done:

First, I assumed the # of even numbers = # of odd numbers, since they occur in pairs. Thus, let $n =$ number of even/odd numbers.

${ s }_{ alpha }=1-2+3-4+5-6+...\\ { s }_{ alpha }+2+4+6+...+n=1+3+5+...+n\\ { s }_{ alpha }+2(1+2+3+...+n)=1+3+5+...+n\\ { s }_{ alpha }+2(\cfrac { n(n+1) }{ 2 } )={ n }^{ 2 }\\ { s }_{ alpha }+n(n+1)={ n }^{ 2 }\\ { s }_{ alpha }+{ n }^{ 2 }+n={ n }^{ 2 }\\ { s }_{ alpha }={ n }\\ $

Comment: So is your given series convergent or divergent?

Comment: The sum of the series does not get larger, so it's most likely convergent.

Comment: Your second line doesn't make sense. How did you add a finite number of terms to an infinite series and end up with a finite number of terms? Also, whats to say the way in which you group terms before adding won't affect the outcome? (Hint: It does).

Comment: I don't understand; I added an infinite number of even numbers to the sum on the left hand side, which ends up being equal to an infinite number of odd numbers. Practically, I've added 2 infinities, that sum to another, or that's what I believe.

Comment: $1-2+3-4+5-6....$ is not divergent?

Comment: Well first, that is not what the second line says. What you have written says you are adding a finite number of terms up to $n$. Secondly, you need to be _very_ careful when manipulating infinite series. I suggest you [read this](https://skullsinthestars.com/2009/03/18/infinite-series-are-weird/) and [this](http://blog.rongarret.info/2014/01/no-sum-of-all-positive-integers-is-not.html).

Comment: @DarkRunner - I'm thinking that $1-2 = -1$ and $3-4 = -1$ and $5-6=-1$ so another form of the series is $-(1+1+1+1+...)$. The point being that the "rate of change" doesn't reduce as more terms are added. Usually, when you add a positive infinity to a negative infinity, you need another line of reasoning to know whether the result is a negative infinity, a positive infinity, some finite value, or undecidable. You can't always say they cancel. They aren't finite numbers, so the rules of finite arithmetic don't always apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I assume you mean $S_{alpha}=-n$

Ok now let us have a small discussion about series.

The series $\sum(-1)^n n$ is divergent and grossly so.

“Divergent series are the invention of the devil, and it is shameful to base on them any demonstration whatsoever.”—N. H. Abel

"But what went wrong in my proof?" I hear you ask. Well some results that we imagine to always hold true fail when manipulating series even sometimes convergent series (cf. semi-convergence).
Associativity and commutativity both fail.
You cannot permutate the terms of a series or group them in the order you like.
You must use theorems like Fubbini's theorem or generalized associativity which require a summable family which (1,-2,3,...) is certaintly not.

"But I saw everybody do that on youtube" you reply. Well yes but what you are seeing is an over simplification of much more complicated arguments.

I invite you to read up on Cesàro's convergence.
And if you really have time read up on the Riemann zeta function and its analitical continuation which allows you to define (and yes I say define) the sum of some divergent series.

In the meantime listen to wise Abel and never use divergent series in proofs.